# How to get ACS Token in Metro App (C#)

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, token, acs

I'm programming a Metro app, in which the user should authenticate using acs.

Now I have included a nuget package (`Windows8.Identity.AccessControl`) and I am able to get the `identitprovider` list and to Login, but how can I receive the token (I need the nameidentifier)?

In the azure toolkit there is a sample, but written in JavaScript and I cannot figure out how to do this :(.

I've worked with acs in combination with a WP7 app and I had no problems there.

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: I understand the JavaScript just fine. But when i create an application in Windows 8 RTM i am not able to get the token back from ACS when using the authentication broker. It might be related to the bouncer url (callback url). I have found a handful of questions with the same issue, and hope to get some positive respond soon :)

Comment: I have the same issue, can get a Success response and I can see a SAML token being sent back in Fiddler2 but no way to get WebAuthBroker to return the token I need. The solution to this may be to dump WebAuthBroker and do a direct HttpClient call or use the new OnlineIdServiceTicketRequest as an alternative. Still looking at this to see

Comment: OnlineIdServiceTicketRequest is only for live ids right? Might be that one just need to use the HttpClient instead.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my solution:
[Does the WebAuthenticationBroker work in Windows 8 Metro App post Release Candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485665/does-the-webauthenticationbroker-work-in-windows-8-metro-app-post-release-candid)

A few things to pay attention too.